# how to detect if a fragment comes from previous fragment or comes from the fragment afterwards using navigation controller component in Android?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I am using navigation controller component. let say I have 4 fragments

A --> B --> C or D

from fragment A, it can only go to fragment B. but if we are in fragment B, it can go to fragment C or to fragment D.

I want to perform method `workXYZ()` in onResume fragment B if it comes from fragment A, and I want to perform method `doSomethingABC()` in onResume fragment B if it comes from fragment C or fragment D.

from fragment A to fragment B I use the code below:

```
val BDestination = FragmentADirections.actionToFragmentB()
Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigate(BDestination)
```

to reach fragment C and fragment D from fragment B, I use global action. because fragment C & D are actually not only used by fragment B. so I use the code like below to go to fragment C or D

```
val CDestination = BFragmentDirections.actionGlobalFragment()
Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigate(CDestination)
```

and from fragment C or fragment D, I use back button to be back to fragment B.

I have tried to use safe arguments boolean `comesFromFragmentA` = true in navigation graph in order to give a sign that fragment B comes after fragment A. but unfortunately, that value on safe arguments boolean `comesFromFragmentA` will remain the same (true) if it comes from fragment C or D.

so what should I do if want to know if the fragment B appears after previous fragment or from the fragment afterward ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragment arguments are mutable so you can change them at any time. Therefore you can update that argument value right before you navigate to signify that future `onResume()` calls will be after you return to this Fragment:

```
// Set the comesFromFragmentA argument to signify that the next onResume()
// will be when you come back to this Fragment
arguments.putBoolean("comesFromFragmentA", false)

// Now navigate
val CDestination = BFragmentDirections.actionGlobalFragment()
Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigate(CDestination)
```

Comment: I have tried this but it will crash my app, when I back from fragment C to fragment B. it will have an error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required argument "comesFromAFragment" is missing and does not have an android:defaultValue. I also have tried set default value like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mZGm.png but I still have that error :(

Comment: @Alexa289 - if you call remove(), then yeah, it won't be in the arguments anymore. Perhaps what you need is to set it to false instead?

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect just updating the argument, rather than removing it.